# How to get the time difference in hours between 2 dates where dates are stored in 12 hour format in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, oracle10g

I have two dates : Date1: `20-Mar-2020 07:35:00 PM` and Date2: `20-Mar-2020 02:42:00 PM`

I have written the query :

```
SELECT     ROUND(minutes / 60, 2) || ' Hours ' 
FROM     ( SELECT  (Date1 - to_date(Date2, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60     AS minutes
  FROM     dual
);
```

But I am not getting the desired result it is displaying 19.58 hours which is wrong , please correct me where am I going Wrong ?

Comment: Be consistent, convert all the dates.

Comment: Just checking, what is the datatype of date1 and date2?

Comment: And if they are `varchar2`, what is your `nls_date_format` set to?

Comment: Why on earth do you store `DATE` values as strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Mat, you need to convert both strings to date, then substract them:

```
to_date(date1, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh12:mi:ss am') - to_date(date2, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh12:mi:ss am')
```

Note that your format specifier was missing the `am` part.

This gives you a result as a decimal number of days, that you can then convert th hours by multiplying it by 24:

```
round(
    ( 
        to_date(date1, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh12:mi:ss am') 
        - to_date(date2, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh12:mi:ss am')
    ) * 24, 
    2
) || ' hours'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c52f50e4f4e8213c47c2e8997d6c4364)**:

```
select round(
    (
        to_date('20-Mar-2020 07:35:00 PM', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh12:mi:ss am') 
        - to_date('20-Mar-2020 02:42:00 PM', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh12:mi:ss am')
    ) * 24, 
    2
) || ' hours' res
from dual
```

```
| RES        |
| :--------- |
| 4.88 hours |
```

Comment: Last doubt , can u plz tell what will be the data type of a column formed after addition of a Date column with a Number column to form a timestamp , for e.g. ,here TRAIN_START_DATE is a Date Type Column , ACTUAL_ARRIVAL_TIME is a Number Type column and in result I have a timestamp value TRAIN_START_DATE+ACTUAL_ARRIVAL_TIME/1440)  AS ARRIVAL_DATE